# how to do a production build with webpacker and vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker

I'm using `webpacker`, `rails` and `vue` together, currently my applications runs fine with `rails s`, however when i run

> RAILS_ENV=production rails server

my webpack loads css files with 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE, and all javascript files comeback with this template:

`<!-- Used to get Vue Page displayed -->`

these files were compiled to `public/assets` and `public/packs` with the contents that appears to be right.

with the commands

> bundle exec rake assets:precompile
>
> bundle exec rake webpacker:compile

what am i missing?

Comment: Try running the `rails assets:precompile` and `rails web packer:compile` with RAILS_ENV=production as well.

Comment: @r3bo0t that did do it, i ran into a different problem but thanks this was resolved.